# How do I update a Web software package from a ZIP file from the command line?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, updates, zip

I have a Web software package installed on my Linux server. I've downloaded an update in a ZIP file, and I want to overwrite only what's changed. (For example, all the core files should be replaced, but any files that I added should not be touched.) How do I do this from the command line?

My method would be to unzip it on my personal computer and then upload the changed files with a GUI file manager, but I want to learn how to do this from the command line.

In my case, I'm trying to update YOURLS on an Ubuntu server, but the question seems generally applicable to most Web software like WordPress or similar.

Comment: One possible way: use `find -mtime xxx -exec chmod -r {} \;` to make R/O the files that have been changed after a certain date and then copy over. But I'm not sure that your method ensures a working server at the end anyway, you could have to integrate changes from the updates.

Answer (score 1):

So (one) of the simplest ways that jumps to mind is to download the zip file, extract it somewhere temporary, delete the files that you don't need, then replace the YOURLS files with the updated ones you have just downloaded.

To download the file (using wget or curl) and extract it to a temporary directory:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir update
cd update
wget http://linktozipfile/file.zip
```

or

```
curl http://linktozipfile/file.zip -o file.zip
```

then

```
unzip file.zip
```

---

Now we can decide what files we do not need, and remove them with the rm (remove/delete) tool.

```
rm config.php
rm someotherfileidontwannareplace.php
```

Then we can replace all files by moving all our updated files into the same directory, and thus replacing old files.

```
cd ..
rsync -av newfolder/ oldfolder/
```

---

If we simply need to add new files then we can do a similar method but use the `--existing` flag on mv, to not overwrite existing files.

This would look like

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir update
cd update
wget http://linktozipfile/file.zip
unzip file.zip
cd ..
rsync -av --existing newfolder/ oldfolder/
```

Comment: I should have been more clear. The `config.php` file is something I added. The package ships with a `config-sample.php`. So all I need to do is move anything in the ZIP file into the Web server directory while leaving alone anything I added.

Comment: Will this also keep things in subfolders? For example, will moving an almost empty folder from the ZIP file on top of a folder that has a bunch more things in it keep all the things I added, or will it replace the whole folder?